# Not able to create dynamic subnode using jstree functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Changed the Title in 2023, as it is mentioned oFF-Topic. But Wanted to Informed the functionality existed, I have worked on the functionality and replied with the answer for my question.

Please verify the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/samueltoepke/wh72zf8b/ to better understand the issue mentioned.

Ian newbie to jquery, iam working with jstree. I am able to create tree with first of values but iam able to create childnodes to the childs present in the same tree.

i could do this

- myttree

  ```
      mytreeval1
      mytreeval2
      mytreeval2
  ```

but i couldnot do this through code

- myttree

  ```
       mytreeval1
          subtreeval
          subtreeval
       mytreeval2
       mytreeval2
  ```

---

i tried the following code.

```
$('#jstreedemo').jstree('create_node', 1, 'inside', 'mytreeval1', node_callback(), true); function node_callback(){alert("Iam here");}
```

creating tree and adding nodes are in different functions();

How to acheive this? anyone help me out with this.

Comment: again with the off topic. this is the second time today i found exactly what i was looking for only to have the moderators ruin it. please stop doing this. you're not doing good, you're doing harm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this has worked for me

```
  var position = 'inside';
  var parent = $('#jstreedemo').jstree('get_selected');
  var newNode = { state: "open", data: {'mydata'} };

  $('#jstreedemo').jstree("create_node", parent, position, newNode, false, false);
```

Comment: The above solution doesn't work.

Need to add a reference to "check_callback" in "core" when creating the tree.

$("#categories")
  .jstree({
    "core" : {
        "data" : managerTeam,
        "check_callback": true
    }
});

Also, the "create_node" line should look something like this:

var newID = $('#categories').jstree('create_node', '#', {text:'Foo'});